# Count number of posts by author in a category

Tags: count

What is the optimal method for getting the number of posts by an author in a category? I'm not looking to get the posts themselves, just a count of them.

[count_user_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) returns a count of all the posts of a user in a post type, but there is no option to filter by category. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In one specific category or every category the author has written a post under?

Comment: In one specific category.

Comment: How are you identifying the category? By ID? Slug? etc. Same with Author

Comment: Identifying both by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by creating a custom `WP_Query` and then counting it.

```
$args = array( 
   'author' => 1,
   'cat'    => 5,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$my_count = $my_query->post_count;
```

Just change `1`  and `5` to the Author ID and Category ID respectively.

Alternatively you can use the category slug or author's **nice name** (NOT name!) as well:

```
$args = array(
   'author_name'   => 'bob',
   'category_name' => 'editorial',
};
```