# Author post count in category

Tags: posts, categories, author, count

I want to count authors post count in a specific category. How do i do that?
I have red this thread here but still can't fiure it out.

[Count number of posts by author in a category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261302/count-number-of-posts-by-author-in-a-category)

Edit: This is what i got and tried but doesnt work at all.

```
$user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID')

$args = array(
   'author_name'   => $user_id,
   'category_name' => 'categoryname',
};               
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        
            echo $my_count = $wp_query->post_count;
            
wp_reset_postdata();    
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code. It shows authors post count from a specific category by category slug name.

```
$user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

$args = array(
   'author'   => $user_id,
   'category_name' => 'category_slug_name',
);    
 
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$my_count = $my_query->post_count;

echo $my_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the posts for this.

Instead, just call the method `get_posts()` which will return an array of posts and then just count the number of posts in that array.

```
$user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

$args = array(
   'author_name'   => $user_id,
   'category_name' => 'categoryname',
);               
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

$posts = $wp_query->get_posts();
$my_count = count( $posts );
echo $my_count;
```

Reference

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_posts/

Comment: I get result 0. Category name is correct.

Comment: Maybe you need a few more parameters to find the correct posts. Have a look through  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters and see if there's anything in your posts that won't be found by the defaults. In particular consider post_status and post_type.

Comment: What i can be missing? Im tryin to find out but can't understand what im missing.

Comment: Problem was 'author_name' should be 'author' but wierd thing is taht your code prints all posts also which i don't want and also never ends printing them. How to fix these issues?